# App inventor 2 slideshow of images from the web

Tags: android, app-inventor

I want to make a simple slideshow photography app in App Inventor 2. I basically have a large number of images that I want to store in the web and display them as a slideshow in App Inventor 2. I don't want to upload them directly in the app because that may take a lot of space. The user will need internet connection to access the images. I need tips on how to store the images and what do I use to display them in the app ? Do I use TinywebDB ? Or is there another way of doing it ?

Thanks for your time. Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You could store your images in your Google Drive or on your own web server and access them from there...

Create a list of the URLs to all images, see also
[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

To display the images, you could modify [this snippet](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2flung) to your needs, which uses the `Canvas` and its `Flung` event...

---

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)